# Power BI - Parent Child Visualization

Tags: powerbi, dax, modeling, powerbi-desktop

I would like to perform following visualization.
Following is the table.

```
+---------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+-----------+--+
| Customer Name | Customer ID | Location Name | Location ID | Rating | Parent Name | Parent ID |  |
+---------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+-----------+--+
| Customer 1    |          10 | Location 1    | L1          |     23 | Null        | Null      |  |
| Customer 1    |          10 | Location 2    | L2          |     43 | Null        | Null      |  |
| Customer 2    |          20 | Location 21   | L3          |     42 | Customer 1  | 10        |  |
| Customer 2    |          20 | Location 22   | L4          |     54 | Customer 1  | 10        |  |
| Customer 3    |          30 | Location 31   | L5          |     65 | Customer 1  | 10        |  |
+---------------+-------------+---------------+-------------+--------+-------------+-----------+--+
```

Output should include Location Name and Rating.

```
+---------------+--------+--+
| Location Name | Rating |  |
+---------------+--------+--+
| Location 1    |     23 |  |
| Location 2    |     43 |  |
+---------------+--------+--+
```

It has 2 filter Customer Name and Include Child Customer. Include Child Customer has 2 options "Yes" and "No".

If user selects "Yes" option then report should include locations of child customer.
As I am new to Power BI, I am not sure how to model data or achieve this functionality.
Sorry for all formatting issues.

Thanks.

Comment: Parent-Child Hierarchies are rather special for Tabular models, give a look at this link: [https://www.daxpatterns.com/parent-child-hierarchies/](https://www.daxpatterns.com/parent-child-hierarchies/)

Comment: Can you show more examples what your expected results are? You have selected just the two columns of the first table, filtering them with unknown criteria.